# How to configure an Azure Active Directory web application for Sharepoint Online permissions

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I'm building an *Azure AD* web application. This web app needs to access *Office 365 Sharepoint Online* APIs. For example, the web app needs permissions to read the users in a *Sharepoint Online* site.

I am trying to configure my web app to allow Sharepoint Online site admins to grant it the above permissions. This is done in the Azure Portal under `Active Directory > My Directory > Applications > My Application > Configure`.

When I try to do this, under the section "permissions to other applications" I am unable to find *Office 365 Sharepoint Online* under the list of applications:

[image]

**Why is this and how can I fix it?**

PS - For reference, this is what I would expect to see when configuring my web app (taken from this [Azure documentation article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/#BKMK_MultiT)):

[image]

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/#BKMK_MultiT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the screenshot you post. It seems this Azure AD is not a Office 365 tenant AD. You need to [Associate your Office 365 subscription with Azure AD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2015/04/30/set-up-your-office-365-and-azure-ad-tenant/#AssociateSubscriptions) first.

For more details, please refer the article [Set up your Office 365 and Azure AD tenant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2015/04/30/set-up-your-office-365-and-azure-ad-tenant/#AssociateSubscriptions)

Comment: Many thanks. This appears to be just what I needed and I'll test it soon. Question: Does this mean my Azure AD web app will only be able to obtain permissions from the associated O365 account? (I'm guessing the answer is no but want to make sure)

Comment: Yes, the app under the Office 365 tenant AD can declare the permission of Office 365 Apps (SharePoint Online, Exchange Online).